# As400 using STRSQL and mailing? to replace VBA code

Tags: sql, vba, excel, ibm-midrange

My current solution involoves importing data from my As400 into excel and then using VBA to check conditions and send email out via outlook.

I was wondering if there is a way to possible to trade my VBA code for a SQL statement and do this at set time (every week). i was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction.Thanks

Comment: SQL is very powerful, so it is quite possible that you could.  Your question is too broad because you don't explain what Excel is doing.

Comment: The VBA code is checking if a user has filled out his/her time card(if the user has logged 37.5hr)  . If said user has not, it sends a reminder.

Comment: Depends how your time data is stored, if it's `USER|DATE|CLOCK IN OR OUT?|TIME|` then it will be very difficult using SQL. If it is `|USER|DATE|HOURS|` Then it might fairly easy, but then you have to set up the SMTP server in the DB2 and then set up the job to do it every week.

Comment: The data itself is |USER|DATE|HOURS| . I'll look into a setting up a SMTP server in the DB2. Thank you for the help Cody

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The technically correct answer to your specific question is no.

Because, STRSQL is an interactive program; you're not going to be able to run it at a set time every week.

However what you're generally asking to do: extract data via SQL, perform some business logic over the data and send out an email, is perfectly doable on the IBM i.

You need something to tie all three steps together.  In the IBM i world, that something would generally be RPGLE and/or CL.  You'd use embedded SQL in an RPG program to retrieve the data, then your choice of APIs to send the emails.  CL doesn't support embedded SQL like RPG does.  But you can issue an SQL statement using the [Run SQL (RUNSQL)](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/sqlp/rbafyrunsql.htm) command to build a temporary table and then read the resulting table in CL and use for example the [Send SMTP Email (SNDSMTPEMM)](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/cl/sndsmtpemm.htm) command to send an email.

You could also conceivably dispense with the RPG or CL; instead using an SQL stored procedure.  However, the resulting stored procedure isn't easily directly called from the built in job scheduler access via the Work with Job Schedule Entries (WRKJOBSCDE) command.

Comment: Probably easily enough scheduled, e.g. with the RUNSQL or …; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39331040/how-can-you-run-a-stored-procedure-from-an-ibm-command-line

Comment: True, but I was thinking error handling might leave something to be desired when a schedule job that just does a RUNSQL.  And if you're going to put it in a CL to schedule it, there's no real reason to go with a SQL stored proc.

Comment: A CL RCVF/send-mail loop seems efficient enough.

Answer (score 1):

I agree Charles. do a CLP with RUNSQL, SNDSMTPEMM and planed with WRKJOBSCDE

But you can do it too:

Do an extern program on Windows (vb, vbs, PowerShell, C# ... langages you want use) and execute your query on iseries (with ODBC by example or with native dll)

Comment: Depending on what is actually the nearly-unexplained-scenario, just send out emails with a URL so the recipient can obtain the data/results soon after they receive/read the email; thus the results [obtained with the SQL] could even be up-to-the-minute, instead of stale information.

Comment: And add a to the task scheduler.